# Python. Изменить значение в yaml

Tags: python, yaml

Нужно изменить значение в yaml файле
файл:

```
singleuser:
  image:
    name: hub/k8s-network-tools
    tag: "1.2.0"
```

Написал вот такой скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import yaml
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Скрипт')
parser.add_argument('key', type=str, help='key')
parser.add_argument('value', type=str, help='value')
args = parser.parse_args()

with open("values.yaml") as f:
    try:
        list_doc = yaml.load(f)
        
        for arr in list_doc:
            arr[args.key] = args.value

        with open("values.yaml", "w") as f:
            yaml.dump(list_doc, f)

    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
user@myPC test % python change_values.py "singleuser.image.tag" "1.2.1"
change_values.py:13: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  list_doc = yaml.load(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "change_values.py", line 16, in <module>
    arr[args.key] = args.value
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
user@myPC test %
```

Подскажите что ни так тут, или как это правильно делается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list_doc` - это обычный словарь:

```
{'singleuser': 
    {'image': 
        {'name': 'hub/k8s-network-tools',
         'tag': '1.2.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Соответственно, нужно поменять значение словаря по соответственному ключу. Пройти по дереву ключей можно примерно так. Я тут зафиксирую аргументы, с парсингом командной строки разбираться не хочу, но приспособить должно быть легко это решение к реальным `args`:

```
with open("values.yaml") as f:
    try:
        list_doc = yaml.load(f)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)

args1 = "singleuser.image.tag" 
args2 = "1.2.1"    

item = list_doc
for key in args1.split('.')[:-1]:
    item = item[key]
    
item[args1.split('.')[-1]] = args2
        
with open("values.yaml", "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(list_doc, f)
```